# The results changed even though seed is fixed

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, python

I am using a reinforcement learning model for some tasks.
and for the model, I am using stable_baselin3 and for the environment, I am using the gym.

I made a small change in the environment and the results became poor now when I rolled back that change the results didn't match the previous results even though I had made no change in the parameters or data.

The seed of the model is fixed so there is no chance that this could be due to random initialization and I have tested this on my model before by running it multiple times to see if gives the same results for the same seed and it did.

I checked that version of NumPy and the torch I used didn't change during my two runs.
and I also tried changing them manually and the results were the same for all the versions.
I am sure that the change I made is rolled back properly because it was a very small change.

Can anyone suggest a list of things that can cause results to change that will help me debug the problem?

I am setting seed for NumPy, torch(used by stable_baseline3), and random. I am not running anything in parallel. I am using the PPO model of stable_baseline3.

I am using below-given function for seed, it is provided by the stable_baseline3 library.

```
def set_random_seed(seed: int, using_cuda: bool = False) -> None:
    """
    Seed the different random generators.

    :param seed:
    :param using_cuda:
    """
    # Seed python RNG
    random.seed(seed)
    # Seed numpy RNG
    np.random.seed(seed)
    # seed the RNG for all devices (both CPU and CUDA)
    th.manual_seed(seed)

    if using_cuda:
        th.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
        th.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
```

Comment: If you use NumPy, PyTorch and Regular python, you may well have 3 (or more) seeds needing setting to manage all the PRNGs. You don't say which seeds you are setting? Also, some libraries cope badly with RNG seeds in multi-threaded code, so worth mentioning if you are using multi-threading or multi-process to run environments in parallel.

Comment: @NeilSlater Thanks for the reply and suggestions. The thing is I checked running the code multiple times before, and results never changed for the same data and parameters, and I am not able to re-create this again it just happened once.

Comment: This seems to be a programming issue, so it's off-topic here. We focus on the theoretical aspects of AI, which also includes RL, of course. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details.